# Can I permanently add to PATH in windows using batch?

Tags: windows, batch

Is it possible to permanently add `c:/project/bin` to `PATH` i windows using only batch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This command will permanently set the current user's "Path" variable:

```
setx path "%PATH%;C:\Project\Bin"
```

The next command will adjust the system variable instead of the user variable:

```
setx path "%PATH%;C:\Project\Bin" /M
```

Comment: You might not want to use `setx` because it could result in a corrupt Path as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10411111/470749